# pass mutable reference from javascript to c

Tags: c, node.js, swig, v8, node-ffi

I've got a c-wrapper that calls into my library (not written in c). I have used SWIG to generate interface_wrap.cxx for javascript target:

```
swig -c++ -javascript -node interface.i
```

and used `node-gyp configure` and `node-gyp build` to successfully get the shared object. Now I can go to the nodejs prompt and call my c functions successfully:

```
nodejs
> var abc = require('./build/Release/shared_lib_name`)
> abc.c_create("Hello")
```

This successfully works where the signature of c function is:

```
int32_t c_create(const char* p_char);
```

However there are functions with signatures such as:

```
int32_t c_fun_0(int32_t* p_int32);
int32_t c_fun_1(char* p_char);
```

which take in a pointer to a non-const (mutable object) with the intention of modifying it.

The following is what i want to achieve but my lack of javascript background does not help me:

```
$ node
> var abc = require('./build/Release/shared_lib_name')
> var some_int = 0
> var same_string = <how to reserve X bytes ?>
> abc.c_fun_0(&some_int)
> abc.c_fun_1(&some_string)
```

How do i call c functions which will mutate the stuff that i pass from javascript ?

Comment: Did you figure this out?